# Does the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2, t \mapsto (t^3, t^2)$ have a history?

Tags: functions, math-history

I heard one mathematician briefly mentioning that the function  $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2, t \mapsto (t^3, t^2)$ is very famous and has a history.

Do you know what was meant by that?

Comment: Of course: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicubical_parabola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“It seems that $f$ is the historic earliest example of a *curved* path of whom the length of compact segments of that path (similar to the length of *straight* path's segments) may be calculated exactly and purely *algebraic* (even  polynomial in expressions of square root!) from the coordinates of start- and endpoint: that was not considered possible (since Aristotle) concerning *curved* paths.”

Roughly translated from Peter Dombrowski, Wege in euklidischen Ebenen: Springer, 1999.